# Are there two normal forces here?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, acceleration

In this question the normal force direction on the collar was determined to the left, while there is a possibility to be to the right direction also since the collar contacts the rod in both directions, how can someone explain this? [image]

Comment: What does the normal force on the collar have to do with this problem? Also, can we assume no sliding friction since the coefficient of kinetic friction is not given?

Comment: It is a smooth rod, so there will no longer be a friction force

Comment: OK, but why do you care about the "normal force" on the collar? It has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Hibbler bock solved it using the normal force

Comment: To me, this is simply a conservation of mechanical energy problem.

Comment: That's it!! Thanks Bob. You helped me well

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter which way you assume the force is going;  the math will tell you if you picked wrong.  Specifically, assuming that the normal force is pointing left really means that you have defined the positive direction for that component of the force to be to the left.  If, for some reason, the force was actually pointing to the right, then you would find (after you solved for all the forces) that you had a negative value for that component of the force.

(I should also note that actually knowing the normal force is not necessary to solve this problem, but that's not what you asked, and actually explaining how to solve it without using the concept of the normal force would violate the homework policy.)

Answer (score 1):

The spring is in tension because its length is always greater than it's unstretched length of 1m.

If, for example, the blue rod has diameter for example of 20cm and the collar has a slightly greater inner diameter of 20.01cm (in reality the collar will be slightly bigger than the rod).

Then the left hand side of the collar is in contact with the blue rod and pulled against it on that side, but the other side of the collar isn't in contact with the rod.

The contact force then acts on the collar to the left.

Answer (score 1):

For almost all problems is does not matter which way you have the direction of forces in your free-body diagrams. If you predict a direction that is incorrect then you will notice after some calculations that the force will be negative (meaning that it points in the other direction). For this case it seems that you are wondering why the normal force of the collar points to the left. To best understand this draw the FBD (free-body diagram) for the collar. It will have a force pulling it to the right due to the spring but we know it does not move to the right due to a opposite force pulling it to the left and that is the normal force from the rod (that the collar is sliding on).

Answer (score 1):

The normal forces are not needed in this analysis. If you consider the spring, collar, and earth as the system, then you can consider the system as being isolated. That means total mechanical energy is conserved, or

$$KE_{initial}+GPE_{initial}+EPE_{initial}=KE_{final}+GPE_{final}+EPE_{final}$$

Where $KE$ is kinetic energy of the collar, $GPE$ is gravitational potential energy of the collar, and $EPE$ is elastic potential energy of the spring.

Since this is essentially a homework and exercise type problem, that's as far as I can go. But I think you can proceed from here.

Hope this helps.